# How to add parameters to Angular transition?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-animations

Trying to add params to transition same as in animation but seems transition not supporting parameters. It says: `The provided transition expression "{{transition}}" is not supported`.
Please check reproduction in Stackblitz: [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-transition-playground-mlizkr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Hope someone can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you are using it the wrong way. Triggers nor transitions are not to be interpolated, only animation definition with the use of `useAnimation`

https://angular.io/guide/reusable-animations#creating-reusable-animations